# Fail to install python Library MetaTrader5 on wine (No matching distribution found for MetaTrader5)

Tags: python-3.x, lib, wine, metatrader5

I'm trying to install the [python library MetaTrader5](https://pypi.org/project/MetaTrader5/) on my machine (Linux Debian 11) in order to use some python scripts on Linux to interact with the MT5 software running on wine.

To do so, i tried to follow [this procedure](https://pypi.org/project/mt5linux/) but in step 3 when i use this command in a linux terminal:

```
wine ./drive_c/windows/syswow64/cmd.exe
Z:\home\.wine>python -m pip install MetaTrader5
```

i have this message error:

```
0150:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation HEAP_INFORMATION_CLASS 1 not implemented!
0158:fixme:file:server_get_file_info Unsupported info class e
0158:fixme:file:server_get_file_info Unsupported info class e
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MetaTrader5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MetaTrader5
```

My configuration is:

Wine: wine-9.0

Python on wine: Python 3.11.8

Linux: 6.1.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux

When i use the -vv option on pip, it displays lots of messages of this type

`Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags (cp312-cp312-win_amd64) are compatible`

Can someone tell me where i'm wrong ... ?

EDIT; I have finally found a solution on [this page](https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/354796#comment_42337361).
This procedure described for Ubuntu works as well for Debian. I had to downgrade python to version 3.8. I haven't tested yet this solution on higher version, but if i have time, i will and post my results here.